# Enable Chunked Transfer Encoding in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, chunked-encoding

I have an ASP.NET 3.5 website residing on IIS7. I am using dynamic compression and wanted to see if I can enable chunked encoding. Is there some setting on IIS or web config that enables it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set Transfer-Encoding to chunked, explicitly or implicitly, in an ASP.NET response?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595460/how-can-i-set-transfer-encoding-to-chunked-explicitly-or-implicitly-in-an-asp)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, calling Response.Flush() will set the Transfer-Encoding to chunked.  And actually I think setting Response.BufferedOutput will set it to chunked everytime Response.OutputStream is flushed.

That is unless a Content-Length has been set, then it just flushes the output without setting chunked.

Comment: I was having a different issue, but your answer pointed me in the right direction. Thx.

Comment: This is not true. Calling Response.Flush() does not add the 'Transfer-Encoding' to the response headers. At least not in all asp.net versions, which version are you using ?

Answer (score -1):

If you edit the IIS configuration you can set the `<asp enableChunkedEncoding />` element / attribute to set this.

Comment: where that section is?