# How to set content length as long value in http header in java?

Tags: java

I am writing a web server in java that is transferring file upto 2GB fine. When I searched for the reason, I found like java HttpServelet only allows us to set the content length as int. As the maximum size of integer is 2GB, its working fine upto 2gb when I am using response.setContentLength method. Now the problem is bydefault response.setContentLength has the parameter of integer. So it is not taking long value as parameter. I have already tried 
       response.setHeader("Content-Length", Long.toString(f.length()));
       response.addHeader("Content-Length", Long.toString(f.length()));
but nothing is working. All time it is failing to add content length when it is a long value. So please give any working solution for HTTPServletResponse so that I can set the content length as long value.

Comment: You probably shouldn't send such big files through a servlet. Have you tried not setting `Content-Length` and sending your file using [Chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)?

Comment: Others have tried : http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4187336
Servlet API does not permits it. Have you tried sending it it anyway without Content-Length?

Answer (score 11):

You can also use below sample code.

```
long length = fileObj.length();

if (length <= Integer.MAX_VALUE)
{
  response.setContentLength((int)length);
}
else
{
  response.addHeader("Content-Length", Long.toString(length));
}
```

Comment: Have you actually tried this, or are you just guessing?

Comment: @EJP, the header name is correct "Content-Length" and there is no size restriction in the [w3c ref](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), so what do you mean? That some browsers cannot handle long content lengths - as in the comment of Yura's answer?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
long length = ...;
response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(length))
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Actually that i have also tried. But it is seting content length with 0 whenever long value is coming..

Comment: That's strange - could you please try `response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(1048576))` and check HTTP response again?

Comment: Great, this works in Tomcat7. setContentLength((int)len) broke my 206-partialcontent video streaming for VLC player. Value as string did the trick. I don't have any pre+postprocess filters on a servlet url if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set it at all.

Just let it use chunked transfer mode, which is the default. There is no Content-Length header in that circumstance. See @BalusC's comment under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2595460/207421).

Answer (score 0):

Do not set it and use chunked encoding. Also beware of **HEAD** requests = these requests should return the same content-length as **GET**, but not sending the actual body. Default implementation of **HEAD** in *javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet* is done by calling **GET** on the same URL and ignoring all the response body written (only counting characters) - see the following fragment:

```
protected void doHead(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    NoBodyResponse response = new NoBodyResponse(resp); // mock response (not writing)
    doGet(req, response); // performs a normal GET request
    response.setContentLength(); // this uses INTEGER counter only
}
```

The problem is that the content length counter is also integer. So I recommend overloading **doHead** method also and not setting the content length at all (you might want to leave **GET** call also to save time generating the giant file).