# request.getContentLength() return 0 when file size is greater than 2gb

Tags: servlets, file-upload, struts2, content-length, http-content-length

Using a file upload in my project as :

```
 <s:form id="uploadData" action="UploadAction" namespace="xyz"   validateFields="false" method="post"    enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

But the request.getContentLength() method returns correct value for less than 2 gb and 0 for anything above it.

The probable reason being 
datatype of the content-length as int. Is there any other way where the request parameter: content-length can be converted into long type 
in order to support uploads greater than 2gb.

please guide us how to convert the content length request header to long to support file upload greater than 2gb

Comment: Are you using x32 or x64 ?

Comment: Have you tried to get it from the header?

Comment: @joaumg we are using x64

Comment: @AleksandrM we can get the header but we don't know how to set the request header content length to long type

Comment: Set? You were talking about getting it, not setting. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/11466905/1700321.

Comment: @AleksandrM We asked how content length can be converted to long type to support upload greater than 2gb . Is there any other approach  for upload greater than 2gb

Comment: Don't set it at all.

Comment: ContentLength is useful for a response... for a request, what's the point ?

Comment: @AleksandrM please guide us in what direction we should move to upload the file size greater than 2gb

Comment: @AndreaLigios i am new to file upload i am unable to understand why getContentLength() return 0 when file size is greater than 2gb and the correct filesize when it is less than 2gb

Comment: @AndreaLigios what extra changes i need to incorporate to upload file greater than 2gb as content length is 0

Comment: How do you think uploading a file depends on a content length?

Comment: @AleksandrM http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/200708.mbox/%3C46C9B803.7010607%40christopherschultz.net%3E  from this link we understand that the request content is limited to 2gb . so we think that this is the probable reason why the file of size greater than 2gb is not uploading

Comment: So you haven't actually tried anything yet? And there is a paragraph in that mail that explains how to do what you ask.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the [getContentLength()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getContentLength--) method in the Servlet API is defined as `int`. Actually, it should return `-1` for files (requests) bigger than 2gb.

If you're using Servlet API 3.1 (e.g. Tomcat 8), you can use [getContentLengthLong()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getContentLengthLong--) method.

Comment: thanks for the support, we are using servlet api 3.0 with tomcat 7 and the request is not generating for the file size greater than 2gb