# doFilter() fails to get any request for the file upload > 2gb

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload, servlet-filters, servlet-3.0

For my struts project the doFilter() fails to get any request from the file upload form in cases the size of the file is greater than 2gb.
Below is the code fragment:

**Filter (class is FilterUp) is as follows:**

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
{   
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    ** check request **
}
```

**jsp is :**

```
<s:form id="uploadData" action="UploadAction" namespace="xyz" validateFields="false" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

**web.xml (for filter class FilterUp) is:**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>FilterUp</filter-name>
    <filter-class>abc.xyz.FilterUp</filter-class>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>autoTimeout</param-name>
        <param-value>1800</param-value>
     </init-param>
</filter>
 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>FilterUp</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

For my jsp the form is submitted as a XMLHttpRequest via the underlying javascipt. Now when I upload a a file (lesser than 2gb) ,in my dofilter() method
I have checked the uri and request length for the request.They are as expected via the action called in the jsp form and the file size.The file upload works fine in this case. But in case where the file size is greater than 2gb ,in my doFilter() method no request is available 
for the file upload action called by the form submit(for file size greater than 2 gb). Thus the upload does not proceed further in such cases.

I am using Tomcat 7 and servlet 3.0. Is this any issue as per this [bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53454).
What do I need to do to support larger than 2 gb file uploads, so that the request reaches the doFilter() method.
`Do I need to change the max-request size of my filter in web.xml? Can it be done in above case because <servlet> tag is not used here.`

What changes do I need to make in order that the request reaches my servlet.

Comment: Are you sure there is no request available? Aren't you hitting [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34741419/request-getcontentlength-return-0-when-file-size-is-greater-than-2gb/34746879) problem (i.e. request is there, but the content length is 0 or -1)?

Comment: @ Jozef , I have checked the request uri details. It is not hitting the action associated with the form.

Comment: How is your filter configured (in `web.xml`)? You should give people enough information to be able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @ Jozef , The web.xml has been updated above for the filter you requested. Is it possible to increase the maximum size of the request for this filter.

Comment: No relevant answers on this query. Please help me out!!

Answer (score 0):

The default maximum file upload size in Tomcat 7 is 2GB.
Check

```
`$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml`
```

and configure the connector:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           maxPostSize="4294967296"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

This will set the maximum file upload size to 4GB.

Comment: I have tried the same but it does not work in this case. The request for large uploads still does not reach the doFilter().