# How to disable Transfer Encoding: chunked for ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack, transfer-encoding

Is there a way to configure ServiceStack to not add the transfer-encoding:chunked in the response of the HTTP header and disable this encoding type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net) just works over raw ASP.NET `IHttpHandlers` so follows the standard behaviour of ASP.NET applies. This [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595460/how-can-i-set-transfer-encoding-to-chunked-explicitly-or-implicitly-in-an-asp) provides hints in how to change Transfer Encoding behaviour in ASP.NET.