# setting Transfer-Encoding header not working with no error message

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, iis-7.5

I am sending a page to the client in chunks, by calling `Response.Flush()` in the middle of my page. This is so the browser will get the first part of the html, and can start downloading resources while my server continues to process the rest of the request.

Because of certain 3rd party services between my IIS server and my client (CDN, Firewall, Load Balancing, etc.) I need to set the header `Transfer-Encoding: Chunked` so they will know that the response will return in chunks.

I try setting the header by calling : `Response.Headers.Add("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");`

For some reason when i do this, I get a blank page back after waiting quite a long time, even when contacting my IIS server directly, without going through all the 3rd parties. When attaching to process to debug, I don't see any errors.
Removing the 'Transfer-Encoding' header works, but I need this header for some of the 3rd parties I'm using.

Anyone know how I can set this header in my web application ??

Btw - I also tried setting this header in 'Response Headers' section in IIS directly, and the response is still empty when doing this.

Comment: It seems that chunked transfer encoding requires the data to be encoded in a specific format. It is not clear in your question that you perfom this encoding. Do you ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding

Comment: @jbl - Thanks! I investigated this further and realized that calling `Response.Flush()` in asp.net unfortunately does NOT output the data in the format needed to use the header `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`. The response is sent, but the browser doesn't know how to analyze it. If you add this as a proper answer I will reward you with the bounty!

Comment: @jbl - you're welcome! Thanks for the answer, i looked a while for this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the description on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), Chunked Transfer Encoding requires the response body to be encoded in a specific way, one of main points of the described format being :

> Each chunk starts with the number of octets of the data it embeds
>   expressed as a hexadecimal number in ASCII followed by optional
>   parameters (chunk extension) and a terminating CRLF sequence, followed
>   by the chunk data. The chunk is terminated by CRLF. If chunk
>   extensions are provided, the chunk size is terminated by a semicolon
>   followed with the extension name and an optional equal sign and value.

As far as I know, calling `Response.Flush()` does not generate this specific markup. It just empties any buffered response content to the client.

You may have a look at "When does the server use chunked transfer encoding?" in this answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2711405/1236044

It seems to imply that, with the correct settings, IIS should automatically switch to Chunked Transfer Encoding when needed

Answer (score 0):

The server will be using chunked transfer encoding if you disable buffering:

Set `context.Response.BufferOutput` to `false`

[According to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595460/how-can-i-set-transfer-encoding-to-chunked-explicitly-or-implicitly-in-an-asp)

You might further need to set `Server.ScriptTimeout` (in seconds) to avoid your script being interrupted.